# How it's supposed to use Anvil in multi module Android projects

Tags: android, dagger-2, square, anvil-di

I'm going to use **Anvil** in my project.

https://github.com/square/anvil

But I can't figure out what is desired model of usage for it? Should I have a single global **AppScope** and merge all bindings from every `:core` and `:feature` module into it? Thus, every `:feature` module adds it's bindings into **AppScope**, thus every `:feature` knows everything about any other `:feature`. This sounds messy, am I right?

I've not seen any possibility to have dependent scopes. For example, **MyFeatureScope** that depends on the **AppScope**. So only particular `:feature` module actually contributes it's bindings into **MyFeatureScope**, but they still could use general-purpose bindings from **AppScope**.

- does **Anvil** supports such dependencies between it's Scopes?
- should I have one global **AppScope**? Or should I have a set of isolated scopes - one per `:feature` module - that could somehow depend on **AppScope** with "common bindings"?

Comment: Check this article. It will help you to start with Anvil:
N26 Path to Anvil: https://dev.to/marcellogalhardo/n26-path-to-anvil-abd
Showcase project: https://github.com/marcellogalhardo/hilt-to-anvil

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately it's up to you to decide how to structure your application. Anvil supports multiple scopes and components, precisely like vanilla Dagger 2.

> does Anvil supports such dependencies between its Scopes?

Scopes do not "depend" on each other. Components (and subcomponents) do. Anvil does support these dependencies.

> should I have one global AppScope? Or should I have a set of isolated scopes - one per :feature module - that could somehow depend on AppScope with "common bindings"?

Do whatever makes the most sense to you. In my application, I use different components to separate pure Kotlin classes and Android-dependent classes.

Let me know if you'd like me to elaborate or demonstrate code samples.